# Capture the error output of a foreground command using plumbum

Tags: python, plumbum

I'm using the plumbum python library (http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/) as a replacement for shell scripts.

There's a command I want to run that, when it fails it outputs the paths to a file I'm interested in:

```
$ slow_cmd
Working.... 0%
Working.... 5%
Working... 15%
FAIL. Check log/output.log for details
```

I want to run the program on the foreground to check the progress:

```
from plumbum.cmd import slow_cmd

try:
    f = slow_cmd & FG
except Exception, e:
    print "Something went wrong."

# Need the error output from f to get the log file :(
```

When the `slow_cmd` fails, it throws the exception (which I can catch). But I cannot obtain the error output from the exception or from the `f` future object.

If I don't run the `slow_cmd` on the FG, the exception contains all of the output and I can read the file from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is, `FG` redirects the output straight to your program's stdout. see https://github.com/tomerfiliba/plumbum/blob/master/plumbum/commands.py#L611

when output is redirected this way, it doesn't go through plumbum's machinery so you won't get it in the exception object. if you're willing to block until `slow_cmd` finishes, a better solution would be to read from stdout yourself. here's a sketch:

```
lines = []
p = slow_cmd.popen()
while p.poll() is None:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    lines.append(line)
    print line
if p.returncode != 0:
    print "see log file..."
```

a more elegant solution would be to write your own ExecutionModifier (like `FG`) that duplicates the output streams. let's call it `TEE` (after http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))... i haven't tested it, but it should do the trick (minus `select`ing on stdout/err):

```
class TEE(ExecutionModifier):
    def __init__(self, retcode = 0, dupstream = sys.stdout):
        ExecutionModifier.__init__(self, retcode)
        self.dupstream = dupstream
    def __rand__(self, cmd):
        p = cmd.popen()
        stdout = []
        stderr = []
        while p.poll():
            # note: you should probably select() on the two pipes, or make the pipes nonblocking,
            # otherwise readline would block
            so = p.stdout.readline()
            se = p.stderr.readline()
            if so:
                stdout.append(so)
                dupstream.write(so)
            if se:
                stderr.append(se)
                dupstream.write(se)
        stdout = "".join(stdout)
        stderr = "".join(stderr)
        if p.returncode != self.retcode:
            raise ProcessExecutionError(p.argv, p.returncode, stdout, stderr)
        return stdout, stderr

try:
    stdout, stderr = slow_cmd & TEE()
except ProcessExecutionError as e:
    pass # find the log file, etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! I had implemented something similar to your first solution. But it kind of breaks on commands with fancy output like increasing percentages (without adding newlines) and colors.

I thought there may be already a `plumbum` way to do this. I'll implement something like the proposed `TTE`. Is there any possibility this would be implemented on `plumbum` in the future?

Comment: I created a ticket for this: https://github.com/tomerfiliba/plumbum/issues/53 it'll probably get incorporated into v1.2

Comment: i fixed this up to use `select` and submitted a patch, which was just merged  :)  thanks for the inspiration!  https://github.com/tomerfiliba/plumbum/pull/117